# Internet doesn't work on Xubuntu 12.04 via Wi-Fi connection

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, internet

I have a problem with Internet on Xubuntu 12.04 via Wi-Fi connection. I have a Wi-Fi router without any encryption. I try to connect to the Wi-Fi router, I see the connection, but I cannot visit any website.

I found another one Wi-Fi router (not mine) also without any encryption and I can connect to this Wi-Fi router and visit websites.

Can anybody give me an advice what should I do to resolve my problem with my Wi-Fi router?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the settings of the router. I used the following IP address: 10.0.0.0. When I changed the IP address to 192.168.1.1, everything worked.